# My laptop doesn't turn off, and doesn't wake up after sleep

Tags: windows, sleep

I recently bought a Lenovo V570 laptop and installed Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1 on it. I've found that whenever I turn the laptop off, the screen turns off but the laptop is still turned on; I then have to press the turn off button for five seconds.

If I put the laptop to sleep, I cannot wake up my laptop. I have to turn it off by pressing the button for five seconds and start it up again.

Any ideas?

Comment: The negative votes are unnecessary, voted to move to superuser.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a site for hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

Typical checklist would be:

1. Install *all* drivers from Lenovo's support site. Some laptop manufacturers tweak some hardware to meet their requirements such that 'vanilla' drivers won't work properly on the laptop.
2. Install all updates and hotfixes using Windows Update.
3. BIOS update might be necessary.
4. A quick research on Lenovo V570 shows it ships with 2 GB of RAM. Have you upgraded the RAM to more than 4 GB? If not, you should definitely upgrade it or use 32-bit Windows 7 Pro instead (64-bit OS on a system with 4GB or less RAM is an overkill).

Answer (score 0):

My advice is take it to the dealer. It's their job to make it work properly.
Also, it indicates device drivers problems. Software versions.

Mine has to do with WIFI, every time I use it my laptop does the same as yours.